# F# Type 'int list' does not match the type 'int'

Tags: types, f#

I'm trying to construct a list which contains numbers of the Fibonacci sequence, but when I try to call the function later on it tells me that int list doesn't match int,

```
let rec fibonacci x list =
    if List.head list > x then List.tail list
    else fibonacci x (List.append (List.head list + (List.head (List.tail list))) list)


let x = 10
let list = [1;2]
let fibonacciList = fibonacci x list
printf "%A" fibonacciList
```

It says the editor is in the function call in the 2nd last line.
I'm new to F# and I'm sure it's a basic definitions error but I can't figure out what it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the call to the `fibonacci` function the compiler actually reveals the true error: `error FS0071: Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type ''a list' for a type inference variable. The types ''a' and ''a list' cannot be unified. Consider adding further type constraints`

This is hard to understand but basically there is something wrong with the implementation. I think the problem is your use of `List.append`. It should take two lists but you provide it with an `int` and an `int list`. You can add one item to the front of a list with the `::` operator:

```
let rec fibonacci x list =
    if List.head list > x then List.tail list
    else fibonacci x ((List.head list + (List.head (List.tail list))) :: list)
```

Here is an equivalent implementation that uses pattern matching to simplify the code:

```
let rec fibonacci x list =
    match list with
    | a :: b :: rest ->
        if a > x then b :: rest
        else fibonacci x (a + b :: list)
```

Note that the compiler warns that the match cases are incomplete. This function will throw an exception if the list has less than 2 items.

Also note that this doesn't work properly: it doesn't produce the Fibonacci sequence. I will leave it with you to fix that.